# Getting large number of items from itemGet() using Zabbix PHP API

Tags: php, api, zabbix

I have run into a bit of a strange problem with the api. I am using historyGet()
to get a large number of items for say over a 5 minute period.

Then I use itemGet() and pass off the itemId as a parameter for Item get and I need the details of all the historical items over a given time frame.

```
$items = $api->itemGet(array(
                    'output' => 'extend',
                    'itemids' => $itemId
                ));
```

The issue here is that I get about 3000 items from history. I build an array of the item ids called itemId[] and pass this 3000(ish) element array as a parameter for itemGet() but it only returns about 746 items at a time.

I believe the bottle neck here is the number of elements read by zabbix from the array. I believe its only read the first bit of array and maybe running out of mem.? and sending only the items Ids read.

Currently I am sending the array in a loop such that it lobs of n number of items from the front as its read by the api.

Another solution maybe reducing the time span such that I get less than 746 items.. but it is not a good long term solution as the data density might increase. A lot.

I am wondering if there is a way to expand the number of items read from the itemId array??

Thanks a lot,
Karan

Comment: In the PHP/Apache log, anything suspicious? One thing that comes to mind would be the PHP max_input_vars parameter, although not sure why would you get less than 1000 results - maybe it first limits to 1000 and then drops some records for other reasons.

Comment: Hey, so I saw the 1000 limit in the PHP api and changed it to 2k.. same issue persists. I think it maybe an issue in the api or perhaps on zabbix side? I get between 746 and 751 items from a call. Right now I am getting 749 pretty consistently. lol

Comment: Can you please show the JSON that you are sending to the API and receiving for it? Not the code but the raw API requests. Shorten the massive parts and show only a few IDs :)

Comment: [3794] => stdClass Object
        (
            [itemid] => 31504
            [clock] => 1470669216
            [value] => 0.0003
            [ns] => 915256031
        )

    [3795] => stdClass Object
        (
            [itemid] => 602098
            [clock] => 1470669216
            [value] => 0.0017
            [ns] => 915256031
        )

    [3796] => stdClass Object
        (
            [itemid] => 24719
            [clock] => 1470669216
            [value] => 0.0002
            [ns] => 915256031
        )

)
Last 3 docs in array from histGet. I extract ids

Comment: so thats the array of docs I get from historyGet and in a for ech loop, I take every itemId from this object and put it into an array. This is what the array looks like
   [3748] => 567338
    [3749] => 23258
    [3750] => 31782
    [3751] => 603586
    [3752] => 24773
(This is from a different api call so index numbers might eb a bit diff.)

Thanks!

Comment: Not the code or data structures you use - raw JSON that is actually sent to (and received from) the API - like in the examples at https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.0/manual/api/reference/item/get